# How to plot properly the following data?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, dataset

Consider the following test data:

```
reg1 = RegionPlot[(x^2 + y^2) <= 1 || 2 <= (x^3 + y^2) <= 5, {x, -3, 
    3}, {y, -5, 5}];
reg2 = RegionPlot[(x^2 + y^3) <= 1 || 2 <= (x^3 + y^2) <= 5, {x, -3, 
    3}, {y, -5, 5}];
sens1 = Cases[Normal@reg1, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity];
sens2 = Cases[Normal@reg2, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity][[1]];
```

`sens1` includes two tables with data, while `sens2` is just one table.

I want to plot the data from `sens1` in one color and the data from `sens2` in another. For this specific example, I may simply use

```
ListPlot[{sens1[[1]],sens1[[2]], sens2}, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic,PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Darker@Red}, {Thick, Gray}}]
```

However, what should I do if the dimensions of `sens1` and `sens2` are a priori unknown?

**Edit**

What if additionally I need to show plot legends, one legend label per all belongings of `sens1` and `sens2`? Again, if the dimensions are known a priori, I may just plot something like

```
ListPlot[{sens2,sens1[[1]],sens1[[2]]}, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic,PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Darker@Red},{Thick, Blue}, {Thick, Blue}}, PlotLegends -> Placed[Style[#, 15] & /@ {"2","1"}, {0.2, 0.15}]]
```

But it is not clear to me what to do if the dimensions are unknown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
reg1 = RegionPlot[(x^2 + y^2) <= 1 || 2 <= (x^3 + y^2) <= 5, {x, -3, 
    3}, {y, -5, 5}];
reg2 = RegionPlot[(x^2 + y^3) <= 1 || 2 <= (x^3 + y^2) <= 5, {x, -3, 
    3}, {y, -5, 5}];
sens1 = Cases[Normal@reg1, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity];
sens2 = Cases[Normal@reg2, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity][[1]];

ListPlot[
 Cases[{sens1, sens2}, _?MatrixQ, All],
 Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Automatic, {Red, Dashed}},
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Style[#, 15] & /@ Automatic, {0.75, 0.85}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, using [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html)

```
ContourPlot[
 {x^2 + y^2 == 1, 2 == x^3 + y^2, x^3 + y^2 == 5},
 {x, -3, 3}, {y, -5, 5},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.8, .85}]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Per comment

```
ListPlot[Cases[{sens1, sens2}, _?MatrixQ, All], Joined -> True,
 PlotStyle -> Flatten[{
    ConstantArray[{Thick, Blue}, If[MatrixQ[sens1], 1, Length@sens1]],
     ConstantArray[{Thick, Red, Dashed}, 
     If[MatrixQ[sens2], 1, Length@sens2]]},
   1],
 AspectRatio -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[{Directive[Thick, Blue], 
     Directive[Thick, Red, Dashed]},
    Style[#, 15] & /@ {"sens1", "sens2"}],
   {.75, .85}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! May I please ask you how to show the lines from `sens1` with the same color independently of the dimensionality of `sens1`?

Comment: And also use only one legend label for all the belongings of `sens1` (please see the edit to the question).

Answer (score 3):

```
plt1 = ListPlot[sens1, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Blue], PlotLegends -> {"sens1"}]
plt2 = ListPlot[sens2, Joined -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], PlotLegends -> {"sens2"}]
Show[plt1, plt2, PlotRange -> All]
```

**Edited:** add plot legend, in response to comment.

Comment: Thanks! Additional question: what if I want to show plot legends?

Comment: @JohnTaylor See edit.

Answer (score 3):

```
RegionPlot[{(x^2 + y^2) <= 1 || 2 <= (x^3 + y^2) <= 5, 
   (x^2 + y^3) <= 1 || 2 <= (x^3 + y^2) <= 5}, 
  {x, -3, 3}, {y, -5, 5}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> AbsoluteThickness[3], 
   2 -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], AbsoluteDashing[5]]}, 
 BaseStyle -> FaceForm[], 
 PlotLegends ->  Placed[
   LineLegend[{#, Directive[#2, Dashed]} & @@ (ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}), 
    {"sens1", "sens2"}], {.7, .9}]]
```

[image]

Working with `sens1` and `sens2`:

```
Graphics[{ColorData[97]@1, AbsoluteThickness[2], 
  Map[Line, sens1, {Depth@sens1 - 3}], ColorData[97]@2, 
  AbsoluteDashing[{6, 5}], AbsoluteThickness[2], 
  Map[Line, sens2, {Depth@sens2 - 3}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! 
Is it possible however to do this if having `sens1`, `sens2` pre-generated (i.e., not having the access to `reg1`, `reg2`)?

Comment: @JohnTaylor, please see the update.